# Prevent SQL Server Connection in ASP.Net Integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

I have a standard ASP.Net Web API Project with a DB setup that looks something like this:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(opts =>
    opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectDb")));
```

This works as intended.

I also have an integration test setup, where I attempt to replace the SQL Server connection with an In-Memory one, for a clean slate every test run:

**ProjectWebApplicationFactory.cs**

```
public class ProjectWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup> {
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
            var prodDb = services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ProjectDbContext));
            services.Remove(prodDb);
            services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(opts => {
                opts.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            });
    }
}
```

This again works correctly when running locally. However, when pushing this code to a build / test server it begins to fail. The initial SQL Server DB Context attempts to connect to a DB prior to getting replaced with the in memory version. Since the server is available locally, but not on the test server, this causes all integration tests to fail before even being able to run.

What is the proper way to prevent the SQL Server Context from attempting to connect while running an integration test?

Comment: Don't call `UseSqlServer` unless you need it to begin with. At the very least, add an `if` block in the option action and add the provider you really want.

Comment: It is needed for a normal run of the application. The only time I _don't_ want it is during an integration test. There's nothing to `if` on in the Startup class.

Comment: So add an `if` that's true only during a unit test. Or don't use *Startup* during a unit test at all, create a ServicesCollection instance in the unit test itself. `AddDbContext` accepts an action. Instead of writing `AddDbContext(opts=>opts.Use....` you can write `AddDbContext(opts=>{ if (...){opts.UseSqlServer...} else { opts.UseInMemory`. It's far easier. to create a `ServiceCollection` with just the configuration you want though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a typo in **ProjectWebApplicationFactory.cs**

This line:

```
var prodDb = services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ProjectDbContext));
```

Should have been:

```
var prodDb = services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ProjectDbContext>));
```

The SQL Sever DB was still being used when running the integration test. This caused it not to fail not on startup, but when endpoints were actually called.

Also related, the in memory database should not be created with a random `Guid` string, but instead a static value, e.g.

```cs
opts.UseInMemoryDatabase("ProjectDb");
```

Answer (score -1):

You are integration testing, but not with the connection string in your project. This means you have your API set up with your production database? If so, don't do that.

The way I handle this is with a couple of techniques, all designed to invert dependencies.

1. Create an interface on top of the class that has the persistence code. As you don't likely have a class, make that as well and move the code over
2. Create mocks or stubs or fakes for your interface for unit testing
3. Swap out implementations using IoC containers
4. Move the connection string loading to instantiation of the persistence class. This can also be done with an IoC container

This gives you flexibility to integration test wherever you want and avoid embedding your production strings in your applications, if that is what you have done.

In this case, you are following some patterns I see a lot, but I find this blending of concerns ends in problems when you don't understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: The OP is already using DI, IoC and all these patterns. The real problem is the code tries to use the DI configuration meant for production in a unit test